# Unable to insert an image in Quill editor in react-native-webview

Tags: android, react-native, quill, react-native-webview

My goal here is to insert an image in **Quill editor** in react-native-webview component as shown below. For which I need access to the **quill** variable in the script tag:

```
 <WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    ref={(r) => setWebref(r)}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    source={{
      html: `<head>
              <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
              <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
             </head>
             <body>
              <div id="editor" >${content}</div>
             </body>
             <script> 
              var toolbarOptions = [[ 'bold', 'italic',],];
              var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
              modules: {
                toolbar: toolbarOptions
              })
            </script>`,
    }}
  />
```

When I try to run following snippet outside webview in react-native, nothing is happening

```
  const url = `https://...`;
  const code = `const range = window.quill.getSelection();
               window.quill.insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', ${url});
              `;
  webref.injectJavaScript(code);
```

But, when I try to run following snippet outside webview in react-native, I am getting the expected result.

```
 const snippet = `document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
                  true; 
                 `;
 webref.injectJavaScript(snippet);
```

Comment: Just an observation. Don't you need quotes around `${url}` like `'${url}'`?

Comment: No. it's aleady in quotes. starting from const range.

Comment: Did you try changing it to what I have suggested? Because from what I see when you have `const url = \`https://blah.com\`;` and `const code = \`....insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', ${url});\`;`, the net result of the injected code would be `.insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', https://blah.com);`. And **it's aleady in quotes** nop. It's in backticks, which makes it a [template string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Thank You, @RomeoSierra ! It worked. Could you please write this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lies in

```
const url = `https://...`;
const code = `const range = window.quill.getSelection();
               window.quill.insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', ${url});
              `;
```

when you have `` const url = `https://blah.com`; `` and `` const code = `....insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', ${url});`; ``, the net result of the injected code would be `...insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', https://blah.com);`, which in the eyes of a JavaScript engine is a syntax error. These backtick demarcated strings are known as [template string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which are used for formatting strings. So, for your code block to work, it should be corrected as follows.

```
const url = `https://...`;
const code = `const range = window.quill.getSelection();
               window.quill.insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', '${url}');
              `; //NOTICE THE SINGLE QUOTES AROUND ${url}
```